# ¿Es posible pasar una clase como parámetro a un método en Java?

Tags: java, poo, clase, diseño-de-clases, metodos

Me pregunto si se puede pasar una clase como parámetro de un  método en Java, de manera que el método haga una serie de comprobaciones sobre esa clase. Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de cobro de impuestos y el enfoque que he pensado es el siguiente:

```
public static double recaudacionCategoría(Class categoria){
        impuesto=0.0;
        for(Vecino v : Vecino.getRegistroVecinal()){
            for (Propiedad p : v.listaPropiedades){
                if(p.getClass()==categoria){
                    impuesto+=p.ImpuestoSobre();
                }
            }
        }
        return impuesto;
    }
```

El IDE no marca este método como error, pero al invocar al método desde la clase principal si.
La sentencia en cuestión:

```
System.out.println(TratamientoImpuestos.recaudacionCategoría(Vivienda));
```

`Vivienda` aparece subrayado en rojo y dice `cannot find Symbol Vivienda`. Las dos clases, la principal y vivienda están dentro del mismo package.

Comment: ¿Qué en realidad estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: Claro que puedes. Pero tu código es confuso. ¿De qué clase es el parámetro que debería recibir `recaudacionCategoría()`? Debes pasarle una instancia de esa clase. Luego, no se entiende de dónde sacas esto: `for(Vecino v : Vecino.getRegistroVecinal()){` ni qué quieres hacer aquí: `if(p.getClass()==categoria){` Dentro del método debes trabajar con la instancia que has pasado en parámetro y puedes hacer cosas como llamar a métodos de esa instancia, etc.

Comment: Tengo un ArrayList que contiene objetos. Quiero ir recorriendo dicho ArrayList y calculando los impuestos de los objetos que pertenezcan a una categoria en concreto. Podemos tener viviendas, naves o locales. La idea es poder contar cuanto se ha recaudado con todos los locales, por ejemplo.

Comment: Pues me temo que falta no sólo clarificar tu código, sino que falta más contexto. ¿Cómo ha sido posible meter en un ArrayList objetos de distinto tipo? ¿Acaso en virtud de la herencia? ¿O bien usas un HashMap anidado u otro tipo de estructura? Sea como sea, ¿esos objetos distintos tienen alguna propiedad que los identifique o no? Estás omitiendo demasiada información que podría ayudar a resolver el problema de la forma más adecuada.

Comment: Me parece más bien un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pasar una clase como parámetro a un método, basta solamente con poner el nombre de la clase seguido del operador `.class`.